# What ports does pip use?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, vagrant, puppet

This is hopefully a quick one to answer, I'm trying to provision a box on AWS with puppet and one of the steps involves a pip install from a requirements file. Something like this: -

```
/usr/local/venv/ostcms/bin/pip install -r /vagrant/requirements.txt
```

The step basically fails because it can't find any of the packages in the requirements file, but when I open the AWS box's security group up to allow "All Traffic" the pip step works.

I'm trying to find the port that pip uses so I can basically have that port, http and ssh open on the box and live happily ever after.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pip runs on `3128` so make sure you have that open in your AWS console.  Otherwise pip will get blocked when attempting to talk to PyPi (or anywhere else it cares to download from).

Comment: To anyone finding this in 2018, I needed to enable port 443 (HTTPS) to get Pip working on AWS.

Comment: I just discovered that since I was running my custom pypi-server on port 8080, I needed to add a netfilter rule like this: "-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT".  I didn't find it necessary to add a specific rule for port 3128.  I hope this can help someone else having this problem.